# Cann't change a occurrence event to exception from Office 365 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

I sent the [UpdateEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api to change the subject of an occurrence event and the server responded success and the exception event info.
Then I sent the [GetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api but the server responded the original event info no matter how many times I've tried.

I've performed the following test steps 15 times, and only reproduce the problem once.

Here is my test steps.

1. Create a repeated event via Office 365 Portal
2. Use ListEventInstance to find out one occurrence event
3. Send UpdateEvent API

```
PATCH /users/xxx/events/xxx
{
   "attendees" : [],
   "body" : {
      "content" : "",
      "contentType" : "html"
   },
   "categories" : [],
   "end" : {
      "dateTime" : "2021-03-17T00:30:00.0000000",
      "timeZone" : "UTC"
   },
   "importance" : "normal",
   "isAllDay" : false,
   "isReminderOn" : true,
   "location" : {
      "address" : {},
      "coordinates" : {},
      "locationType" : "default",
      "uniqueIdType" : "unknown"
   },
   "onlineMeetingUrl" : "",
   "recurrence" : null,
   "reminderMinutesBeforeStart" : 15,
   "responseRequested" : true,
   "sensitivity" : "normal",
   "seriesMasterId" : "AAMkAGQyOWUzZTI4LTUxMTAtNGFlZS1iOTc4LTdlZjNhMjQzMTNlZQBGAAAAAADXfh6DJHy_SqmaAAhA7_5vBwDtmH5o5TGrSqzZy3ybSWSUAAALH8n8AADtmH5o5TGrSqzZy3ybSWSUAABF2xEsAAA=",
   "showAs" : "busy",
   "start" : {
      "dateTime" : "2021-03-17T00:00:00.0000000",
      "timeZone" : "UTC"
   },
   "subject" : "EXCEPTION_EVENT"
}
```

4. The server responses 200 OK with the following response body.

```
{
   "@odata.context" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxx')/events/$entity",
   "@odata.etag" : "W/\"7Zh+aOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS2pHhQ==\"",
   "allowNewTimeProposals" : true,
   "attendees" : [],
   "body" : {
      "content" : "",
      "contentType" : "html"
   },
   "bodyPreview" : "",
   "categories" : [],
   "changeKey" : "7Zh+aOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS2pHhQ==",
   "createdDateTime" : "2021-03-29T02:45:52.6905665Z",
   "end" : {
      "dateTime" : "2021-03-17T00:30:00.0000000",
      "timeZone" : "UTC"
   },
   "hasAttachments" : false,
   "hideAttendees" : false,
   "iCalUId" : "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00807E5031152F8CBA14524D701000000000000000010000000CD25F5DB68799A4A8C5322FAE505D9F4",
   "id" : "AAMkAGQyOWUzZTI4LTUxMTAtNGFlZS1iOTc4LTdlZjNhMjQzMTNlZQFRAAgI2OjXm6fAAEYAAAAA134egyR8vkqpmgAIQO-ubwcA7Zh_aOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS9HTzwAA7Zh_aOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS9ZQEgAAEA==",
   "importance" : "normal",
   "isAllDay" : false,
   "isCancelled" : false,
   "isDraft" : false,
   "isOnlineMeeting" : false,
   "isOrganizer" : true,
   "isReminderOn" : true,
   "lastModifiedDateTime" : "2021-03-29T02:45:52.6905666Z",
   "location" : {
      "address" : {},
      "coordinates" : {},
      "displayName" : "",
      "locationType" : "default",
      "uniqueIdType" : "unknown"
   },
   "locations" : [],
   "onlineMeeting" : null,
   "onlineMeetingProvider" : "unknown",
   "onlineMeetingUrl" : null,
   "organizer" : {
      "emailAddress" : {
         "address" : "xxx@bbb.com",
         "name" : "xxx"
      }
   },
   "originalEndTimeZone" : "Taipei Standard Time",
   "originalStartTimeZone" : "Taipei Standard Time",
   "recurrence" : null,
   "reminderMinutesBeforeStart" : 15,
   "responseRequested" : true,
   "responseStatus" : {
      "response" : "organizer",
      "time" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
   },
   "sensitivity" : "normal",
   "seriesMasterId" : "AAMkAGQyOWUzZTI4LTUxMTAtNGFlZS1iOTc4LTdlZjNhMjQzMTNlZQBGAAAAAADXfh6DJHy_SqmaAAhA7_5vBwDtmH5o5TGrSqzZy3ybSWSUAABL0dPPAADtmH5o5TGrSqzZy3ybSWSUAABL1lASAAA=",
   "showAs" : "busy",
   "start" : {
      "dateTime" : "2021-03-17T00:00:00.0000000",
      "timeZone" : "UTC"
   },
   "subject" : "EXCEPTION_EVENT",
   "transactionId" : null,
   "type" : "exception",
   "webLink" : "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkAGQyOWUzZTI4LTUxMTAtNGFlZS1iOTc4LTdlZjNhMjQzMTNlZQFRAAgI2OjXm6fAAEYAAAAA134egyR8vkqpmgAIQO%2FubwcA7Zh%2BaOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS9HTzwAA7Zh%2BaOUxq0qs2ct8m0lklAAAS9ZQEgAAEA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item"
}
```

5. Refresh the Office 365 Portal website, the event is still a occurrence!
6. Send [GetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API and the server responded the event type is 'occurrence' and the subject is different from what I set in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried mimicking same API calls multiple times but could not reproduce this behavior. Could you try again and see if this is still happening for you?

Also I would suggest, if you are calling API within code, please isolate it and try using POSTMAN/Graph Explorer and see if you still observe discrepancy.

Thanks!